# Unable to debug with this Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have the following `Makefile` and `exe` file doesn't allow me to debug with

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

What could be wrong?

```
APP:= CTCGreddyDecoder

TARGET_DEVICE = $(shell gcc -dumpmachine | cut -f1 -d -)
CXX:= g++

LIB_INSTALL_DIR?=/usr/lib/

ifeq ($(TARGET_DEVICE),aarch64)
  CFLAGS:= -DPLATFORM_TEGRA
endif

SRCS:= $(wildcard *.cpp)

INCS:= $(wildcard *.h)


OBJS:= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS+= -I /usr/local/include

LIBS+= -L$(LIB_INSTALL_DIR) 

all: $(APP)

%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CXX) -c -g -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

$(APP): $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(CXX) -o $(APP) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

install: $(APP)
    cp -rv $(APP) 

clean:
    rm -rf $(APP)
```

When file command was used.

```
file CTCGreddyDecoder 
CTCGreddyDecoder: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=ccc6a10bf4fc6543c54865e07e98c59bdcef1e13, not stripped
```

Comment: I tried `g++ -g ctc_decoder.cpp -I/usr/local/include -o CTCGreddy` this compilation and it works with gdb. What could be wrong with Makefile?

Comment: Probably, the `CFLAGS` variable is set in your shell where you are trying to build your stuff, isn't it?

Comment: Your shell command applies debug to all steps of the process, you only have `-g` when compiling object files. That flag should be part of the CFLAGS variable. Better yet, your makefile should have a debug option.

Comment: You probably need to add `-g` to your linker flags

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I need that.